# How can System.Lazy<T> access private constructor of T?

Tags: c#-4.0, constructor, singleton, access-modifiers, lazy-initialization

I've implemented singleton according to [this page](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy) using `System.Lazy<T>`.

I wonder, how technically can `System.Lazy<T>` access constructor of `T`, when access modificator of constructor is `private`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Lazy<T>` is instantiated with an anonymous method as follows:

```cs
new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
```

Anonymous methods are under the covers just private methods located in the class that defines them. Since this is a method in the class, it is allowed to access any other private members of that class including the private constructor.

The code the C# compiler generates closely resembles the following:

```
Func<Singleton> factory = this.__compiler_generated_method;
new Lazy<Singleton>(factory);

private static Singleton __compiler_generated_method()
{
    return new Singleton();
}
```

Comment: I see, therefore the need to pass constructor of T as an anonymous method to constructor of `Lazy<T>`